# Wpf GridSplitter replaces binding on row.height property

Tags: wpf, grid, binding, gridsplitter

I'm having a hard time with grid splitter. I've bound the `RowDefinition.Height` dependency property to the clr property of the model as presented below.

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height='{Binding Path=Height, Mode=OneWay}' />
        <RowDefinition Height='*' />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

This works fine just until the `GridSplitter` is used. When the height of the row is changed manually with `GridSplitter`, it replaces the binding with the new fixed size (and removes the binding).

Have you got any ideas or workarounds how to create two rows that would be resizable with GridSplitter but still change their height according to the clr property/binding?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the problem is that your source Property `Height` is of type double and `RowDefinition.Height` is of type `GridLength`. Use a converter and it'll work TwoWay

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=Height,
                                    Mode=TwoWay,
                                    Converter={StaticResource DoubleGridLengthConverter}}"/>
    <!--...-->
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

**DoubleGridLengthConverter**

```
public class DoubleGridLengthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new GridLength((double)value);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        GridLength gridLength = (GridLength)value;
        return gridLength.Value;
    }
}
```

---

**Update**
Uploaded my sample application here: http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?pgibb205d65596q

Set the `RowDefinition.Height` by entering a value in the lower `TextBox` and resize the `RowDefinition.Height` with the `GridSplitter`

Comment: This won't work since (I assume that) the GridSplitter removes the binding and sets the height property to a fixed size. Thus the binding is disconnected after resizing the rows.

Comment: @Catfisherman: No, it'll not remove the Binding. When sizing with the `GridSplitter`, the new Height will be set in your source property

Comment: @Catfisherman: Uploaded my answer with my sample project which you can try out which does this TwoWay

Comment: @Meleak: Thanks, I'll try it and post the results here.

Comment: @Meleak: Thanks for help, it works now. I forgot to set the TwoWay mode and returned null in the ConvertBack function.